# Adding reflection to a plane while keeping a perfect white emission

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I want to have a perfectly white background with a reflection of an object. For the perfect white, I decided to use a emissive color, the result is as I expected.

Now if I mix a Glossy BSDF, I have my reflection, but the white is not as perfect as it was before mixing the shaders. Playing with the Fac-value is not bringing be further, because I need the white to be perfect, not with a tradeoff.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please don't go too harsh on me, since I'm a beginner :D

[image: Mix shader results in a not perfect white]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't mind breaking energy conservation laws, try Add (shaders > add shader).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Nodes and overview:

1. You will need to create "fake PBR" shader by mixing **Diffuse** with **Glossy** by **Fresnel**.
2. **Glossy** should have set 0 **Roughness** and **Color** to pure white.
3. Mix them with **Emission** shader - again by **Fresnel**.

[image: nodes]

> **Note:**
>
> I've used black Environment color to show that Emission and Reflection
>   is working, if you set it to white, like in every else node it will
>   give you wanted result.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it after my current project is rendered!